# How to get the publishing options from PublishEndRemoteEventArgs? C#, Sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore, publish, publishing

I'm adding a publish:end method in order to publish particular related items when a items of a certain type are published. I have the OnPublishEnd and the OnPublishEndRemote methods, but I need to make sure to publish to the same publishing targets as the item that was just published. I already have the publisher in the OnPublishEnd event, but I'm not sure how to get it in the remote event:

```
public void OnPublishEnd(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var sitecoreArgs = args as Sitecore.Events.SitecoreEventArgs;
    if (sitecoreArgs == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var publisher = sitecoreArgs.Parameters[0] as Publisher;
    if (publisher == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var rootItem = publisher.Options.RootItem;
    if (rootItem.TemplateID == IEventConstants.TemplateId)
    {
        PublishEventParent(rootItem, publisher);
    }
}

public void OnPublishEndRemote(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var args2 = args as PublishEndRemoteEventArgs;
    if (args2 == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    Item rootItem = Factory.GetDatabase("web").GetItem(new ID(args2.RootItemId));
    if (rootItem.TemplateID == IEventConstants.TemplateId)
    {
        PublishEventParent(rootItem, ???publisher???);
    }
}

public void PublishEventParent(Item item, Publisher publisher)
{
    var adHocPage =
        item.Axes.GetAncestors().FirstOrDefault(x => x.TemplateID == IAd_Hoc_PageConstants.TemplateId);
    if (adHocPage != null)
    {
        publisher.Publish();
    }
}
```

How can I get the publisher/publishing options/publishing targets in the remote event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the whole list of properties you have in `PublishEndRemoteEventArgs` class.

Publish End remote event usually is fired on CD servers. And they should not have any connection to `master` database, so it should not be possible to do any other publishing there.

```cs
public bool CompareRevisions { get; protected set; }

public bool Deep { get; protected set; }

public DateTime FromDate { get; protected set; }

public string LanguageName { get; protected set; }

public PublishMode Mode { get; protected set; }

public DateTime PublishDate { get; protected set; }

public List<string> PublishingTargets { get; protected set; }

public bool RepublishAll { get; protected set; }

public Guid RootItemId { get; protected set; }

public string SourceDatabaseName { get; protected set; }

public string TargetDatabaseName { get; protected set; }
```